# How are private functions/methods labeled on the stack?

Tags: c++, oop

When methods/functions are executed an [activation record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is created on the stack. Activation records generally include:

- Parameters
- Local variables
- Return address
- Return-result address
- Intermediate results

The above list doesn't really say if the function/method is Public/Private.

So my question is: just by observing the run-time stack, how are functions/methods "labeled" on
    the stack to determine if they are Public/Private in terms of C++, Java, or C#?

Comment: Whether a function is public or private is irrelevant when the code is executed. At least in C++, the compiler makes sure that you don't call private functions from places where you shouldn't.

Comment: A) There is no such thing as C/C++, B) In C there is no such thing as methods, classes or private/public access.

Comment: Visibility is a compile-time concern. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @Borgleader: You are correct sir, I have updated my question.

Comment: In C++ at least, they're not. Access specifiers restrict the use of names at compile time, and have no effect at run time. I've no idea what Java might do; you should stick to one language at a time.

Comment: They're not.  The difference between `public` and `private` makes a difference at compile time; it lets the programmer control what methods a user of their class can call, and helps prevents accidents when a caller calls a method it shouldn't.  It has no effect on what happens during program execution.

Comment: What makes you think that their access modifier has any effect on the stack frame? In all these languages, it acts as access control, so that the compiler can ensure their usage only from the desired places. In Java and C#, it also acts as an encapsulation mechanism (in C++ you have to use the pimpl idiom to achieve encapsulation). But beyond that, there is no difference between public and non-public methods, they are all just (sub)routines and are called in the same way.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis You don't have to use the pimpl idiom to achieve encapsulation.  The pimpl idiom doesn't change encapsulation for the programmer; it is mainly used to improve compile times.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar More correctly, the compiler makes sure that you don't use the _name_ of the private member where you shouldn't.  You can still call a private function from outside the class, provided you can call it without naming it (e.g. through a pointer to member function).

Comment: @JamesKanze When I say "access control", I'm referring to the source code. When I say "encapsulation", I'm referring to the binary interface. I'm under the impression that private members in C++ are present in the binary interface and can only be hidden via an opaque pointer, am I wrong?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis As much as they are in Java, or most other languages.  It depends on what you mean by "binary interface", and what you are doing with the class.  Private members affect its size, for example, but that's true in Java as well.  (Perhaps the difference is that in C++, you can allocate instances on the stack, which isn't the case in Java.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I mean that I'm under the impression that if you add/remove private members in C++, you probably have to rebuild anything that has this class as a dependency, because the member offsets are now different. In Java and C#, probably because the offsets aren't encoded in the bytecode (instead, they are calculated by the JIT-compiler), you don't have to rebuild.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis The build procedure _is_ significantly different between Java and C++.  Independently of how private members are handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, access restrictions are for *names*, not functions, data or
whatever else.  All names, including nested types are affected, but only
the names; you can still call a private function from outside of the
class, provided you can reference it somehow (e.g. via a pointer to
member function, or simply because is wasn't private in the base class
which declared it virtual).

Java is largely the same, although the fact that a function is private
means that it is also `final` and not `virtual` (which is not the case
in C++, where `virtual` functions are usually private).

Comment: Thanks @James Kanze, I upvoted and accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering only for **C++**, not Java. You should not tag your questions with multiple languages. The answers for different languages, even closely related languages like C and C++, can be very different.

---

Re

> **”** When methods/functions are executed an activation record is created on the stack.

No, not necessarily. Besides, the usual terminology is **stack frame**. Stack frames are generally necessary to do stack unwinding for exceptions, and also to support debugging, but in special cases (in particular inlining, but also just general optimization like optimization of a tail-recursive call) no new stack frame needs to be established.

Much of the rationale for stack frames has to do with some idealistic ideas about tooling and supporting generally recursive functions. It wasn't always that way. For example, old Fortran was blindingly fast by simply not supporting recursion, and when Donald Knuth wrote his *The Art of Computer Programming* he just let the caller store the return address directly in the return instruction of the called function (but then he also did pretty weird things like abstracting away the difference between decimal and binary at the machine code level, drawing tree structures with the root down in the first edition, and speculating about “reel time” having to do with mounting of magnetic tapes).

---

Re

> **”** Just by looking at the stack, how are functions/methods "labeled" on the stack to determine if they are Public/Private?

They aren't.

There's no such thing as C++ accessibility at the machine code level.

Access specifiers can however influence on the layout of structs. As of C++03 you were only guaranteed increasing addresses for members between access specifiers, and I think that still holds with C++11 and C++14.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with everything here.  A _stack frame_ is a way of implementing an _activation record_, but it isn't the only way; a long time ago, I encountered a C compiler which implemented activation records by dynamically allocating memory on the heap (and freeing it when you left the function); in languages without lexical scope, it's the usual way.  And the support for recursion, today, doesn't have much to do with speed, although in the (very) old days, machines didn't have stacks, and recursion meant emulating one.

Comment: And by the way, storing the return address in the return instruction, or in memory immediately before the function, was frequent practice back then as well.  Knuth didn't invent anything there.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The terminological distinction you draw between *stack frame* and *activation record*, with the former tied to a machine stack and the latter as a more general concept, is not in wide use today. Rather, “stack frame” is the general term today. Regarding the “C compiler” with sloooow dynamic allocation of stack frames :), that could possibly have been a C interpreter, or it could be a misinterpretation, on someone's part, of how things worked on a machine with register file; I’d guess a Sparc-station. Re the speed cost of recursion support, yes that may have changed over time.

Comment: The C compiler with dynamic allocation of the activation records was on a BS2000.  A Siemens machine (at the time---now Fujitsu) which didn't (and I suppose still doesn't) have a stack.  And it really did slow things down enormously.  Such machines were common in the past (and still dominate mainframe architecture), which is why Fortran didn't require functions to be reentrant.  (If functions aren't reentrant, you can use static variables for function locals.)